# YouTube iframe z-index on mobile works before play but not after you click done

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube, z-index, fullscreen

I have a mobile site with a youtube video embedded in a slideshow with left and right arrows overlaying the iframe. The arrows work fine before I click play. They are visible and clickable. Then I play the video and it goes full screen. When I click done and close it, the arrows are still visible on top but no longer clickable.

I have tried messing around with preserve-3d and adding the wmode=opaque to the src and iframe tag with no luck.

I am not having this problem with vimeo embeds, the arrows work before and after they play full screen.